# No left navigation with categories

Tags: magento

I have a big trouble with displaying the left navigation sidebar with product categories.

My category tree looks like

- Default category (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = No)

  - Category (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = Yes)

    - Category 1 (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = Yes)
    - Category 2 (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = Yes)
  - Brand (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = No)

    - Brand 1 (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = No)
    - Brand 2 (Is active = Yes, include in navigation menu = Yes, Is anchor = No)

I have products

- Product 1 assigned to Category and Category 2.

I have set in System > Manage stores, the Root Category option set to Default Category for all stores.

I didn't make any changes in templates.

Breadcrumbs are correct. I can see the product in Category and Category 2, but if I'm in the Category listing I can't see the subcategories listing, so I can't see the Category 2.

What's the problem here?

Comment: do your categories have a template with left column? (`2 columns left` or `3 columns`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Category has the Attribute "isAnchor" set to true there wont be a list of subcategories, instead you get the layerednavigation. Set the "isAnchor" to "No" to get a list of subcategories.